# Pandas: compare & merge 2 dataframe's of columns which contains a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have two different dataframe's which is like below ones,

```
df1:
   class   name
0  I       {'tom':2,'sam':14}
1  II      {'ram':11,'joe':1}


df2:
   class   school area            name
0  I       mount  north view, ca  {'tom':0,'sam':0,'keith':0,'jhon':0}
1  II      zion   garden city, sa {'rita':0,'tommy':0,'kelvin':0,'ram':0,'joe':0}
```

How to compare the df1 with df2 and update the columns of school and area and the resultant df1 is suppose to be?

```
df1:
   class   school  area            name_1              name_2
0  I       mount   north view, ca  {'tom':2,'sam':14}  {'tom':0,'sam':0,'keith':0,'jhon':0}
1  II      zion    garden city, sa {'ram':11,'joe':1}  {'rita':0,'tommy':0,'kelvin':0,'ram':0,'joe':0}
```

- If all the keys of "name" column in df1 is in "name" column keys of df2, then the respective row's "school" and "area" column has to be updated on df1.
- If all the keys of "name" column in df1 is not in "name" column keys of df2, then the respective row's "school" and "area" column has to be updated as None on df1.

How to use this condition in the below expression or is there any other way to do it?

```
  df1 = df1.merge(df2, how='left')
```

Comment: what if it is not matched(different keys) ??

Comment: @pyd it should be updated as None

Comment: so is it just element-wise comparison or needs to be a merge?

Comment: can you add one more row for non match and its expected output

Comment: @pyd yes, the non match rows will be added with None value for the respective columns

Comment: @thushv89, if all the keys in df1.name is matched with df2.name, then it should be merged or else None

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this achieve the purpose? Note that I changed the last row of `df2` to see if None values are correctly populated.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'class':[1,2], 'name': [{'tom':2,'sam':14},{'ram':11,'joe':1}]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'class':[1,2], 'school': ['mount','zion'], 'area':['north view, ca', 'garden city, sa'], 'name': [{'tom':0,'sam':0,'keith':0,'jhon':0}, {'rita':0,'tommy':0,'kelvin':0,'ram':0}]})



df1["name_concat"] = df1["name"].apply(lambda x: tuple(x.keys()))
df2["name_concat"] = df2["name"].apply(lambda x: tuple(x.keys()))

df = df1.merge(df2, how='left', on='class', suffixes=['_1', '_2'])

df[["school", "area"]] = df.apply(
    lambda x: x[["school", "area"]] if all(x1 in x["name_concat_2"] for x1 in x["name_concat_1"]) else [None,None], axis=1)
print(df)
```